# Using select case in SQL to Order By 2 criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How can I get this in the appropriate format for SQL Server 2008?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCustomerFleetList_C        
(        
 @FilterBy NVARCHAR(200),        
 @CustCode  NVARCHAR(30)         
)        
AS        

SELECT 
    CASE @FilterBy
    WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN UnitNo
    WHEN 'EquipmentType' THEN EquipmentType
    WHEN 'Registration' THEN Registration
    WHEN 'EquipmentTypeModel' THEN EquipmentType + ' - ' + Model
    ELSE NULL
  END as 'Items' 
  FROM EcommerceCustomerFleet_C 
  WHERE CustomerCode = @CustCode 
  GROUP BY     CASE @FilterBy
    WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN UnitNo
    WHEN 'EquipmentType' THEN EquipmentType
    WHEN 'Registration' THEN Registration
    WHEN 'EquipmentTypeModel' THEN EquipmentType + ' - ' + Model
    ELSE NULL
  END
ORDER BY 
  CASE @FilterBy 
  WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN LEN(UnitNo) 
  WHEN 'EquipmentType' THEN EquipmentType 
  WHEN 'Registration' THEN Registration 
  WHEN 'EquipmentTypeModel' THEN EquipmentType + ' - ' + Model END
GO
```

The problem lies in this line `WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN LEN(UnitNo), UnitNo`

Comment: What are you trying to do with that? a coalesce?

Comment: Trying to create a stored procedure. Basically what I'm trying to do with ` WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN (LEN(UnitNo), UnitNo)` is to create a proper numerical list when the items are `VARCHAR`. This has worked for me, I'm just not sure of the correct way of implementing it in a `CASE` statement

Comment: Oh, are you trying to order by two things? In that case, put one in there, then another in a separate order by clause. e.g. `WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN LEN(UnitNO)...` followed by another, `CASE WHEN @FilterBy = 'UnitNo' THEN UnitNo END`.

Comment: what does this mean: (LEN(UnitNo), UnitNo). looks like a syntax error

Comment: I would suggest rewording your order by clause to be something like this: `ORDER BY CASE @FilterBy WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN LEN(UnitNo) WHEN 'EquipmentType' THEN EquipmentType WHEN 'Registration' THEN Registration WHEN 'EquipmentTypeModel' THEN EquipmentType + ' - ' + Model END, CASE WHEN @FilterBy = 'UnitNo' THEN UnitNo END` and seeing if you still get the error. I assume you're trying to order by both LEN(UnitNo) and UnitNo only if @FilterBy = 'UnitNo', which this should do. The issue comes about because you're trying to include two separate `ORDER BY` clauses in a single one.

Comment: @ZLK that still causes multiple issues. Please see my complete procedure code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can move sort into the 1st field

```
 Select KeySort = CASE @FilterBy
                  WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN (LEN(UnitNo), UnitNo)
                  WHEN 'EquipmentType' THEN EquipmentType
                  WHEN 'Registration' THEN Registration
                  WHEN 'EquipmentTypeModel' THEN EquipmentType + ' - ' + Model
                  ELSE NULL
                  END
       ,{Other Fields}
 From SomeTable
 Order By 1,SomeOtherField,PerhapsAnother Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to sort so '9' comes after '11' ??  And mix it in with VARCHARS. If that is the case, then these would need to be changed to something like '000009' and '000011'. So:

```
        WHEN 'UnitNo' THEN  REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(UnitNo)) + UnitNo
```